# Why JQuery is not working in JSF (Primefaces)

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

<h:head>

    <script src="/resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.js" ></script>

    <script >

        $j=jQuery.noConflict();

        function appendText() {
            alert('hi');
            var txt1 = "<p>Text.</p>";
            var txt2 = $j("<p></p>").text("Text.");
            var txt3 = document.createElement("p");
            txt3.innerHTML = "Text.";
            $j("p").append(txt1, txt2, txt3);
        }

        function appendList() {
            var item1 = "<li>List item</li>";
            var item2 = $j("<li></li>").text("List item");
            var item3 = document.createElement("li");
            item3.innerHTML = "List item";
            $j("ol").append(item1, item2, item3);
        }
    </script>
</h:head>

<h:body>

<f:verbatim>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<ol>
<li>List item 1</li>
<li>List item 2</li>
<li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
<button id="btn1" onclick="appendText()">Append text</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="appendList()">Append list items</button>
</f:verbatim>
<h:form>
<h:commandButton value="jsf cmd btn APPEND TEXT" onclick="appendText()" id="btn3"/>


</h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

This is simple JSF page with JQuery code in script.

When I run, the page is loading properly. But, it is not calling the JQuery scripts.

I don't know why... can any body please suggest what am doing wrong??

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the script tag where you include jQuery.

Primefaces comes bundled with jQuery, so if you configure the Primefaces Resources servlet correctly in your web.xml configuration file, then it will automatically be included on all of your web pages.

**EDIT:**

Also, you cannot use the $ character to call jQuery on a JSF page, as this is a reserved character for expressions.  You must call jQuery in its long form...

```
jQuery('.example').click();
```

**EDIT 2:**

Also, try not to mix Javascript with both single quotes and double quotes at the same time.

```
        alert('hi');
        var txt1 = "<p>Text.</p>";
```

Pick one quote character and stick with it.  This is good practice.

Comment: Your first edit is incorrect. The `$()` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi BalusC, can you suggest me here please..?

Comment: First answer of maple is the answer to your concrete problem. Just use PrimeFaces-bundled jQuery instead of providing your own which would only conflict.

Comment: Again, this is not the answer to your concrete problem. First answer of maple is the answer to your concrete problem.

Comment: "You must call jQuery in its long form" **this is plain wrong**

Comment: @BalusC, I am using Primefaces 3.0 M1. I guess it is not required to add Primefaces Resources Servlet in web.xml

Comment: M1? Why are you using a beta version instead of a stable version? Heck, version 3.0 is already stable for over a year. The taglib URI has been changed in M4 to `http://primefaces.org/ui`. The taglib URI of `http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui` is generally considered as PrimeFaces 2.x and thus a resource servlet is required. Anyway.. Remove the manually included jQuery file and your problem should disappear.

Comment: I moved to M4 version now, changed the taglib URI and I removed manually included jQuery file. Facing same problem